# using try catch and throw

Tags: c++, try-catch

My understanding of the try function, was to stop errors that could possibly occur between try and catch.
But if I do something like this:

```
std::vector<int> testvector;
testvector.push_back(1);

try{
cout << testvector[53485375345534] << endl;
}catch(...){

}
```

My idea was that it would not cause an error in the expense for memory, but it does nothing in this case, an error still pops up.

Could someone explain the proper reason for using try, so far in my experience, i could have used an if statement beforehand instead, could someone give me an example when you would need a try statement?

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you this but you probably misunderstood the purpose of `try` and `catch`. They are **not** intended to *stop* errors. Instead, they enable you to *handle* errors. Once there's an error, there always be an error.

Comment: also note that the literal `53485375345534` may be too big for your compiler; for your testcase, just use `1` or `2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different kinds of errors:

1. Exceptions. These are the errors your program creates, `throw`s and that you can `catch` and handle.
2. Access violations, system exceptions and so on, aka "crashes". These are very severe, you can't do much when they occur (at least not inside standard C++'s possibilities), so it's best to write correct programs then these wont crop up.
3. Assertions. These are meant to check your program logic and constraints during development and testing. They normally appear only in debug code, i.e. they should be turned off in release builds. If an assertion occurs, in Windows a window pops up saying what went wrong.

I am only guessing here - are you using MS Visual Studio?

MSVC's vector implementation checks the `operator[]`'s argument in debug mode and *asserts* if the argument indeed is within the vector's range. That assertion is *not* an exception, so you can't catch it.

Answer (score 3):

`operator []` does not check for bounds in `std::vector`.

However, `std::vector::at()` does throw an exception. You should use it instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your test case is invalid, `std::vector::operator[]` doesn't do boundry check, also it doesn't throw exception, you are expecting undefined behavior instead of exception. You could try [std::vector::at](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) function

```
std::vector<int> testvector;
testvector.push_back(1);

try{
    std::cout << testvector.at(53485375345534) << endl;
}catch(std::exception& e){
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept of Try-Catch is about handlings errors which could break your program but most often could be handled without doing so.
Your example is a good one for an operation which is totally correct but only if the data you are requesting exists. That "only if" could be handles by the function itself but then you could never react to the faulty input. Instead the function throws in such cases an exception which can be handle by your code if you surround the calling with a Try-Catch.
Within the Catch block it is often appreciated that you inform the user or at least write the missbehavior to a logfile and you could also load default values or even alter the variables and repeat the function call.
Sometimes the Try-Catch is described as "Ask for forgiveness not for permission" (the latter would be a prior If).

In general the Try-Catch can be read in pseudocode as:

```
Try:
    Do what you think is right to do but be aware it could be wrong...
Catch:
    You were too optimistic and should react in a proper way...
```

I hope that helps to understand the Try-Catch concept a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using some functions that you are not sure they are going to work, you'll use a throw statement. For example you want to make a GUI windows, you'll use a try block, so in case windows wasn't created, you'll not end up waiting for inputs on a windows that doesn't exist.